# Why does MS Office interop appear to let you construct an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, com-interop

With Office interop in C#, I can write the following:

```
    protected override Excel.Application Create()
    {            
        return new Excel.Application();
    }
```

This works just fine and calls like this frequently appear in articles about Office interop, but `Excel.Application` is actually an *interface*.

Using object explorer in Visual studio, it appears that the return value of the method is a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`, but the method being called is actually `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.ApplicationClass()`.

So how is `new Application()` actually getting resolved as `ApplicationClass.ApplicationClass()`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Damn, don't know how I missed that one. Thanks.

Comment: This is normal behavior, as you cannot run an interface (it is just a contract). You need a concrete class to actually run behavior. And, yes, @ChrisHaas, it is essentially a duplicate.

Comment: @BenAaronson, I actually had always wondered this, too, which is why I took a little longer to dig around.

Comment: @GregoryABeamer I'm aware of course that you can't *actually* construct an interface, what I was confused about was why you could write `new Application()` and it would know the specific implenting class's constructor to call. But the answer on the other question explains that.

Comment: @BenAaronson - Never sure on here what the depths of knowledge is. Yes, there is some "magic" under the hood in the internals. ;-)